# How to split a text having a character which is combination of comma and space?

Tags: c#, split

I have a following line which I want to split it by comma.

> "Clark Kent，Hello Mr.Wayne，发送于 3:38 PM。"

Sounds easy right? The problem is the text does not contain single comma character. The commas you see in the text is a single character which  is combination of comma and space(Just copy paste the above sentence in your text editor and check it out).

The problem is: I need to split the text by comma. Although I can copy paste the character add it as one of my delimiter characters, I am wondering if I could just convert such texts into text that could be splitted by comma. Well don't worry about Chinese words for now. The similar is the case with the last character you see in the text. Actually, this behavior arises when my application Language is set to Chinese.

[image]

FYI: I thought such comma is non printable/non ascii char but to my surprise, when I printed the text in console, I got:

[image]

Here is my input and expected output:

Input : `"Clark Kent，Hello Mr.Wayne，发送于 3:38 PM。"`

Expected output: `{"Clark Kent", "Hello Mr.Wayne", "发送于 3:38 PM。"}`.

Comment: I think its still not clear. Better you put input , current and expected output.

Comment: Why don't you just `x.Replace("<strangeComma>", "<trueComma><space>")` before the spilt, and you should be fine?!

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help

Comment: @Fabjan "I am wondering if ..... "

Comment: Turns out the `<strangeComma>` is not so strange afterall. It's just a thing called "Fullwidth Comma" from unicode. Hex: 0xff0c. You should be totally fine replacing these the way i have commented above.

Comment: @Chris I know I could do that. I am just wondering if there is any work around without modifying splitter code based on the text we get. Well, the comma at that position is always expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma you are facing is a '[Fullwidth Comma](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0c/index.htm)' (Hex: 0xff0c). A regular unicode character which can be replaced by a comma and space using the string.Replace method:

```
s.Replace("<fullwidthComma>", "<trueComma><space>");
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. That's exactly what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest (same as @Chris suggested in comments) is to replace your strange comma value with regular comma before split.

```
var s = "Clark Kent，Hello Mr.Wayne，发送于 3:38 PM。";
s = s.Replace('，', ',');
var splitted = s.Split(',');
```

Benefit is that if it find strange comma, it will replace else it will process with regular comma.